# How to stop browser to close in playwright after execution using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I have not used any browser close() method but still after execution or any error came browser is closing in playwright...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is intended behavior. Read the docs. Only if you manually create browser context, you need to close it.